# How can I setup client devices to be on different subnet from the hotspot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

Router port 1 is acting as a DHCP server for subnet 192.168.1.0/24. My hotspot access point is connected to router port 1 and is receiving 192.168.1.1 as DHCP client. Now I need the client that connect to my hotspot to get ip address from 10.0.1.x pool.

I wonder how this can be achieved. Last time I use to statically assign my hotspot to be 192.168.1.1 and DHCP server to be issuing 10.0.1.x pool. But I wish that no static ip is needed.

Comment: Can you please share the model numbers of your "router" and "hotspot".  Also please make sure you identify the correct ports everything is plugged into.  For example, from your description I read the following.

Router(port1)----------(port1)Hotspot (((  wireless ))) Laptop

Is this how you are configured?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! Yes the diagram is correct. 
Router is mikrotik ccr1009. Hotspots are mixture of UniFi AC Pro and LinksysWRT54G. We are in the middle of removing all the linksys but I hope there is a solution for this set up

Comment: In order for your UniFi AC to forward all network management and
data packets from one network interface to the other
without any intelligent routing, you must set the Network Role -> Network Mode to bridged.  This will allow for DHCP packets to flow from the Mikrotik ccr1009 Eth1 port through the Unifi AC to your wireless device.